# Maintain usestate for different onclick

Tags: reactjs

Since I am new to react i am trying to maintain state separately for each onclick

```
  const openMenu = (id) => {
    setNavbarOpen(!navbarOpen);
     closeMenu();
  };

const closeMenu = () => {
    setMenuActive(false);

  };
<navContainer isMenuActive={isMenuActive}>
<ul>
                {navItems.map((navItem) => (
                  <NavItem
                    data={navItem}
                    key={navItem.id}

                    onClick={() => openMenu(navItem)}
                  />
                ))}
              </ul>
</navContainer>
```

I am planning to open the menu and close the menu while clicking on same tab.
If first menu is open then first menu should close while clicking.  If I click the second menu instead of closing the first menu the second menu should opened. Now if i click the second menu the first menu gets closed and the second menu is not opening.

Basically I would like to maintain the state separately for each menu. Is it possible or any other ideas?

Comment: Can you add the code for your ``closeMenu()`` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `.map()` function, you can pass in the `name` or `id` of your tab then add that to your state.

Then you can create your logic based on the value of `tab` which will either be equal to the `name` of the corresponding opened tab or `null` if the tab is closed.

```js
const tabs = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "tab1"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "tab2"
  },
]

export default function App() {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState(null)

  const handleOpenTab = (e) => {
    tab === e.target.value 
      ? setTab(null)
      : setTab(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {tabs.map(tab => (
        <input
          key={tab.id}
          onClick={e => handleOpenTab(e)}
          type="button"
          value={tab.name}
        />
      ))}
      <pre>
        {
          JSON.stringify(tab, null, 2)
        }
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Add to state from map]